# Is it harmful to nest too many components inside a single one?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a multi-selectable table component which contains a table-disaply component. Inside the table-display component there is another component called table-row.

```
table-selectable
      | (contains)
      v
 table-display
      | (contains)
      v   
  table-row
```

I am doing this because I would like to make each component genereic enough so that it can be used for other purpose, Howere, I realise it is not easy to pass the action up the the parent component. The reason is that I have to carefuly wire all the actions inside `sendAction` method and the action name inside the hbs file and I feel this probbaly may cause error(s) in the long wrong.

My question is that is it harmful to nest tom nay components inside a single component like the one I did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript prepares an HTML DOM Tree of Objects in a document loaded. This DOM is then available to you to work around with its elements.
Javascript access to HTML DOM is still slower than executing javascript without accessing HTML DOM.
The level you have mentioned is not too deep nested, so far you are you are easy to access the inner elements.
Events generated by elements always propagate toward Execution Context which Javascript engine has created to run the piece of your code. So, you can work with these events on Global level (which is "window" level most of the time) until you are registering the listener with proper HTML element to listen to the proper event, otherwise this will not work. For example, a button fires a "click" event, e.g. 
`document.getElementById('mybutton').addEventListener('click', function() {
console.log('my button clicked');
});`
So far as you are successful to select this button, and bind the "click" event listener, you are OK. But if your element selector is wrong, or you are trying to listen to the wrong event, this will not work.
So far as the volume of the page is concerned, the more the content, the more page load time. Also consider it as an SEO perspective.